# jQuery/JavaScript and document.ready() mid-document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked around for similar questions and I couldn't find an answer...

I'd like for one particular page of my web site to import a file ("clock.js"):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
```

and, on load, to run the function tick() from that page.. in the body of the document.

I know I am supposed to do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(tick);
```

But it doesn't work and I suspect it's because these lines of code are in the middle of the document.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's in the body of my document (I'm importing the head and foot of my website templates, hence why I'm doing this mid-document).

Comment: What is going wrong? Is the tick() function not called at all? where you put the .read(), shouldn't matter. It will be execute after the document is ready

Comment: That should work anywhere.  Do you get an script errors in Firebug?

Comment: @JDelonge: By importing, do you mean including? And if so, by "head" do you mean the `<head>` tag?

Comment: @SLaks: I assume not before downloading jQuery

Comment: Google Chrome's console is not showing any errors, is that close enough to Firebug?

Comment: @MichielvanVaardegem The tick function is not called at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently the code should work. you can try

```
jQuery.getScript("clock.js",function(){
tick();
});
```